# Two mystery slots (8 bytes) on the stack. What is following EBP register value?

Tags: c, linux, x86, stack, 32-bit

I have constructed a model stack frame based on debugging information that I extracted from the executable using GDB. While not an expert, I can follow the assembly code enough to pinpoint the location of some local variables, and, of course, I can use symbol table information to directly query the address of variables and arrays. Unfortunately, I can not account for two "slots" (two 32-bit words [8bytes]) of memory immediately following the $EBP of the stack frame. From my understanding, a standard stack frame for, 32-bit Linux, is laid out, in order of increasing stack (i.e. growing towards lower memory address), as follows:

1. function arguments (parameters)
2. Return address (EIP value of next instruction of the calling function)
3. frame base pointer (stores the address of the calling functions frame base)
4. exception handler information (if applicable)
5. Register values (if pushed onto the stack)
6. local variables
7. allocated buffer space and/or temporary data storage

The 'C' program does not define exception handling information so I'm sure that I can rule that out. Furthermore, I do not see in the assembly code that any registers apart $EBP are pushed onto the stack. Of course, $EAX is used as a workhorse to store many value and perform computations but is never pushed onto the stack. While $ESP is used it is never pushed onto the stack either. The source code is provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
long n = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
FILE *fp = NULL;

void bubble_sort()
{
    long swap = 0;
    long array[39];
    // loading data to array
    printf("Source list:\n");
    char line[sizeof(long) * 2 + 1] = {0};
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        if (strlen((char *)line) > 1)
        {
            sscanf(line, "%lx", &(array[n]));
            printf("0x%lx\n", array[n]);
            ++n;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // bubble sort
    for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
            if (array[d] > array[d+1])
            {
                swap       = array[d];
                array[d]   = array[d+1];
                array[d+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    //output result to stdout
    printf("\nSorted list in ascending order:\n");
    for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
    printf("%lx\n", array[c]);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* a main program further up stack memory that calls bubble sort 
    code omitted because it is not relevant*/
}
```

Unfortunately, there is too much assembly to post here. There are only five local variables allocated in bubble_sort:  swap, array[], line[], rawtime, timeinfo. I can account for all of them in GDB using the assembly and source tables. What are those mystery 8 bytes immediately following $EBP on the stack? Is it some predefined offset allowed for by the compiler? Does it have to do with default system alignment? I'm pretty new to these things. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

FYI, this code was not compiled with optimization turned on. ASLR is off as is stack canary support because this is a buffer overflow lesson.

Comment: Stack protection canaries? Are they initialized with some code that is messing with gs or fs? Can you at least post the first handful of instructions that deal with these locations?

Comment: should be turned off. The assignment address buffer overflow, which is why I am constructing a stack. I don't even think it matters what those two values are for the exploit but it is driving me crazy.

Comment: the i386 SysV calling convention requires 16-byte stack alignment before a `call`, and gcc normally aims to have ESP 16-byte aligned after reserving stack space.   It also passes args on the stack, so it has to leave room to push them.

Comment: Also, you compiled with optimization disabled, so gcc isn't even trying to do anything efficiently, including allocate stack layout.